# How to use --since option with docker logs command

Tags: linux, logging, docker, docker-container

I want to look at last 1 hour of docker container log using `docker logs --since` option. Which value I should provide for `--since` parameter?

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @jww This question doesn't appear to be specific to Unix or Linux, unless Windows doesn't use dashes for command line options.

Comment: @Andrew - Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. On-topic/off-topic has nothing to do with command line options.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

as the help says

`--since string   Show logs since timestamp (e.g. 2013-01-02T13:23:37) or relative (e.g. 42m for 42 minutes`

I would do

`docker logs mycontainer_or_id --since 60m`

This syntax is correct according to my active container

Answer (score 22):

Please refer to the Docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/#usage).

```
docker logs --since 1h
```

> The --since option shows only the container logs generated after a given date. You can specify the date as an RFC 3339 date, a UNIX timestamp, or a Go duration string (e.g. 1m30s, 3h). Besides RFC3339 date format you may also use RFC3339Nano, 2006-01-02T15:04:05, 2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999, 2006-01-02Z07:00, and 2006-01-02.

Answer (score 4):

You may want logs from a **specific date**, but docker might not like your date's format.

In such cases, check whether the UNIX `date` command can parse it:

```bash
$ date -d "your date here"
Wed Oct  5 12:46:17 GMT 2022
```

If `date`'s output looks right, then you can use `date -I` to produce a format that docker understands.

```bash
$ docker logs my_container --since "$(date -I -d "your date here")" | less -RX
```